# cross join issue in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sap-ase

I have been using Hibernate 3.2 intailly for my J2EE application with Spring 2.5.Recently I wanted a feature of hibernate 3.5(BigInt Identity support).So I have upgraded my hibernate and now I facing a different issue with my queries.

HQL Query:-

```
select table from tableVO table where tableVO.subTableVO.id=:tableVO.id
```

SQL Query:-

```
select table_1_ID from table cross join subTable where subTable.id =table.id
```

I see that cross join is being done by hibernate which is not accepted by Sybase ASE. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Check the dialect you have set in hibernate configuration.  I'm going to assume you're running on Sybase ASE 15.x.  As you found out, Sybase does not (yet) support CROSS JOIN, which is what the SybaseDialect attempts to use.  Instead, use [SybaseASE157Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SybaseASE157Dialect.html) or [SybaseASE15Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SybaseASE15Dialect.html).  It will generate syntax that should look like:

```
select table_1_ID from table, subTable where subTable.id =table.id
```

Comment: How was this not upvoted!?  Thank you a year and a half later, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can change **hibernate dialect**,

in **hibernate.cfg**

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">com.YourProject.YourDialect</property>
```

in your dialect class you should enter the syntax you want executed.

**example dialect** change for DB2

```
public class DB2390Dialect extends DB2Dialect 
{

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select identity_val_local() from sysibm.sysdummy1";
    }...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am using a SybaseAnyWhereDialect.Any hints on this??

Comment: @user288794 you need to override the method that generates the faulty sql. try looking in your dialect class for the syntax generated.

Comment: Yes.I am still not able to crack it.

Comment: @user288794 did you try changing the dialect?

Comment: Yes.Used Syabse11 dialect which avoids ANSI joins.

Comment: @user288794 Great. so why not approve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with implicit joins in Hibernate.  You can fix it by aliasing your joins:

```
select table from tableVO table
join tableVO.subtableVO subtable
where subtable.id=:tableVO.id
```